# Extracting attribute from escaped XML tag in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, youtube

So I've been working on some XSLT to modify YouTube's RSS XML, and of course as soon as I got it working, they've changed their formatting.  Before, each video's unique ID was stored between `<videoid>` tags, which you could then use to create a URL.  But now the only way to get a video's URL is from a tag like this

```
<media:player url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>`
```

which is contained within `<media:group>` tags.

The way I've been trying to get at it is

```
<xsl:value-of select="media:group/media:player@url" />
```

but doing that gives me a compilation error that says

```
xsl:value-of : could not compile select expression 'media:group/media:player@url'
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with that?

Also, as a side note, I want to do something similar with

```
<xsl:value-of select="media:group/media:thumbnail@url" />
```

however there are several `<media:thumbnail>` tags for each entry; would this just grab the first one, or would this potentially cause errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing a `/` in your XPath. Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="media:group/media:player/@url" />
```

As far as DOM API is concerned, attributes *belong* to an element. The XPath goes about it in a slightly different way. Child nodes live on the `child::` axes (which is the default so you rarely see it used explicitly) and attributes live on the `atribute::` axes (you can get there with the abbreviated `@`). When constructing an XPath expression you are basically building a sequence of [location steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Location-Steps) separated by `/`. An attribute is "one location step" away from the element owning it.

To the second part of your question. The selector will create a sequence (think node list) of all nodes that match the expression and will do what the `xsl:` instruction prescribes to do on that sequence. In your case ([`xsl:value-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of)), all `@url` of all matching `media:thumbnail` will be put together in a node-set that will be further [converted to a string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order

So you will get the value of the "first" one. That said, I would argue that running `xsl:value-of` on a sequence of more than one node is not really intuitive (even though the spec clearly says what it will do) so you would do a favor to someone reading the code after you if you be more specific with your selectors. Something like: `media:group/media:thumbnail[1]/@url`

Comment: Dude, I'm almost tearing up here; you're a life saver.  Once I got the attribute thing working, I decided to go back to the old method of just appending the video id, which I extracted using substring-before and substring-after.  Thank you so much, I was driving myself crazy trying to fix it.